# How can I convert a Stream of Mono to Flux

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a method that try use WebClient to return a Mono

```
    @GetMapping("getMatch")
    public Mono<Object> getMatch(@RequestParam Long matchId) {
        return WebClient.create(OpenDotaConstant.BASE_URL).get()
                .uri("/matches/{matchId}", matchId)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Object.class);

    }
```

It can return result that I expected.
Then I try to create another method to support List as params

```
    @GetMapping("getMatches")
    public Flux<Object> getMatches(@RequestParam String matchesId) {
        List<Long> matchesList = JSON.parseArray(matchesId, Long.class);

        return Flux.fromStream(matchesList.parallelStream().map(this::getMatch));
    }
```

But this time return a weird result.

```
[
    {
        "scanAvailable": true
    },
    {
        "scanAvailable": true
    }
]
```

I'm new to reactive-programming, What is the correct way to combine Stream and Mono,and then convert to the Flux?

Comment: Hi. Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want to re-use the `getMatch` method and return a list? The response as you've posted looks reasonable. Are you expecting something else?

Comment: @MuratOzkan yes,re-use the method getMatch is my purpose,and I already got the answer,thanks anyway

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably, what you need is the following:

```
@GetMapping("getMatches")
public Flux<Object> getMatches(@RequestParam String matchesId) {
    List<Long> matchesList = JSON.parseArray(matchesId, Long.class);
    return Flux.fromStream(matchesList.stream())
               .flatMap(this::getMatch);
}
```

Instead of:

```
@GetMapping("getMatches")
public Flux<Object> getMatches(@RequestParam String matchesId) {
    List<Long> matchesList = JSON.parseArray(matchesId, Long.class);
    return Flux.fromStream(matchesList.parallelStream().map(this::getMatch));
}
```

Notes:

- Basically, you expect `getMatches` endpoint to return `Flux<Object>`. However, as it is written - it actually returns `Flux<Mono<Object>>`, therefore you see the strange output. To get `Flux<Object>`, I suggest, first, create `Flux<Long>` that are match ids, and then `flatMap` the result of calling `getMatch` (that returns `Mono<Object>`), this finally gives `Flux<Object>`.
- Also, there is no need to use `parallelStream()`. Because you're already using reactor, everything will be performed concurrently on reactor scheduler.

Comment: It's really helpful,it 's seems that I misunderstood the meaning of Reactor.I'll try to find some blog or document about spring flux to continue my study.
Thanks~